# Dynamically generating SQL data on new page with PHP

Tags: mysql, sql, dynamically-generated

I'm having trouble with this website I am creating.

Basically I'm trying to create news articles on a page that once you click on the article you'd be taken to a page that would load the content for that article. Is it possible to set it up in a way that I can load the content on a new page depending on the SQL primary key of the article selected?

I can load the articles on the page from the sql database no problem its just determining what data is loaded on a new page that is beating me.

Thanks in advance for any advice anyone can offer in this, even if its just pointing me in the right direction. 
I have tried searching online first with no luck so far.

Comment: Anything you have tried? Without any code shown and a specific problem we can't help, and the question will be considered 'too broad'.

Comment: You can create a page that checks the `URL` for the `ID` of the news article, then display the contents based on that `ID`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$_GET` to create a dynamic content using one page only

**EXAMPLE:**

*article.php?news_id=1:*

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['news_id'])){
        $newsID = $_GET['news_id'];
        //query all the data you need using that $newsID
    }
?>
```

Comment: Amazing. Thank you soo much.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the news-id as variable in url and get that variable using $_GET method,then execute the sql query.

```
     <?php
     $id =$_GET['id];
     ?>
     mysql-"Select * from Table where id =$id"
```

Comment: A code showing your suggested answer will make your answer much better